# Janky translateY on Reanimated View inside of ScrollView as user scrolls

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated

I am using react-native-reanimated v1. I want to make a `<Reanimated.View>` appear as if it is fixed within the scroll view by using `translateY`. GIF of how of it should behave is at very end of post. I have simplified the code in the snippet below, and I have the full working code in the snack.

https://snack.expo.io/@noitidart/reanimated-scroll-view

As you scroll, you notice the position of the view is not staying fixed at the top. I attached a video taken on iOS of the snack.

If I add `scrollEventThrottle={16}` it fixes the issue on iOS, but on Android if you scroll even a little faster than normal you see the transform is lagging. I think there should be a way on iOS without the `scrollEventThrottle` property too, it doesn't make sense to me that we need this as reanimated is supposed to update every frame.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
const ReanimatedScrollView = Reanimated.createAnimatedComponent(ScrollView);

export default function App() {
  const translateY = Reanimated.useValue(0);


  const handleScroll = Reanimated.event([
    {
      nativeEvent: nativeEvent => Reanimated.block([Reanimated.set(translateY, nativeEvent.contentOffset.y)])
    }])

  return (
    <ReanimatedScrollView onScroll={handleScroll}>
      <Reanimated.View style={{ transform: [{ translateY }] }} />
    </ReanimatedScrollView>
  );
}
```

#### Janky on iOS

[image]

#### Janky on Android (with and without `scrollEventThrottle={16}`)

[image]

#### Here is video of how it should be (with `scrollEventThrottle={16}` on iOS, but it doesn't fix up Android)

[image]

Comment: Why are not you moving that fixed text outside of the `ScrollView`?

Comment: @LeriGogsadze it's just a simplified case of a bigger thing where this was needed. I can definitely share that insight with you, but it might lead to a big discussion, and a XY discussion.